# Elliptic Curve is DH function or PKI?

Tags: elliptic-curves

can we reuse same ECC key on TLS for long terms or it must be used just once? *(i mean can we use ECC like RSA?)*

is there patent free ECC implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, TLS supports [ECDSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_DSA) for signing and [ECDH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) for key exchange. You can read about it [RFC 4492](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt). Notice you don't get RSA, but you get signing and key exchange which are major functions of TLS.

Related material:
[How do I create an ECDSA certificate with the OpenSSL command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992036/how-do-i-create-an-ecdsa-certificate-with-the-openssl-command-line)
[SSH key-type, rsa, dsa, ecdsa, are there easy answers for which to choose when?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/ssh-key-type-rsa-dsa-ecdsa-are-there-easy-answers-for-which-to-choose-when)

As far as patents go, see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/can-ecc-be-used-without-infringing-on-patents). I am not aware of any ecc libraries that claim to not violate patents. [Bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) says it is up to you to figure that out. Openssl's ecc implementation was supposedly built to avoid patent issues.

**Is elliptic curve a DH function or PKI**
Neither really. There are elliptic curve variants of ElGamal and [RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3969/why-are-elliptic-curve-variants-of-rsa-chiefly-of-academic-interest). Depends exactly what your definition of PKI is though as you can have ECDSA certificates with a public and private key. You can then start a PKI by signing other certificates, etc.